# Относится ли метод к конкретному классу

Tags: php, ооп

Доброго времени суток!

У меня возникла проблема и пока нет конкретного решения. Хотелось бы сделать проверку, относится ли метод к конкретному классу или нет. method_exists() работает по всем доступным методам, а надо именно по классу. Т.е. речь идет именно о наличии в нем того или иного метода...

```
class firstClass {

    public function firstMethod() {}
    private function secondMethod() {}

}

class secondClass extends firstClass {

    public function thirdMethod() {}
    private function fourthMethod() {}

}

$obj = new secondClass;

$methodName = 'firstMethod';

if(method_exists($obj,$methodName)) {

}
```

Точнее хочется определить это в случае с наследованием для дочернего класса.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function check_method($obj, $methodName)
{
    $class = new ReflectionClass($obj);
    $methods = $class->getMethods();
    return [] != array_filter($methods, function($v) use ($methodName, &$obj) {
        return $v->name === $methodName && $v->class === get_class($obj);
    });
}

$obj = new secondClass;
$methodName = 'firstMethod';
var_dump(check_method($obj, $methodName));
```

https://ideone.com/BERrFP

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [hasMethod()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php) класса [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
class firstClass {
    public function firstMethod() {}
    private function secondMethod() {}
}

class secondClass extends firstClass {
    public function thirdMethod() {}
    private function fourthMethod() {}
}

$refObj = new ReflectionClass('secondClass');

if( $refObj->hasMethod('firstMethod') ) {
    ...
}
```